# Recovering bounty that was never awarded

Tags: support, bounty

I offered a 50 point bounty on this question: [Facebook and Crawl-delay in robots.txt?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20825/facebook-and-crawl-delay-in-robots-txt)

As it turns out, the question was a duplicate, and the bounty was never awarded, yet i have still been deducted that 50 points...or have I missed something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the [meta.SO FAQ on the bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067). Relevant bit:

> If no answers meet these criteria, the bounty ends without it being awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

Also, that question isn't a dupe(yet) as far as the technicalities of being closed, etc. which was actually being *prevented* by the bounty. Apparently mods can refund bounties, though there isn't really any detail about acceptable cases, so you'll have to talk to them about whether this fits.

Comment: Thanks - I did a cursory look/search, but could have looked harder...

Answer (score 1):

The points are deducted when the bounty is created. Once this is done, those points are gone - you do not get them back, regardless of the outcome.